# regex: 0 to N lines between 2 expressions

Tags: regex

Here is a problem I have under https://regex101.com/
I can have two regular expressions, one with and another one without lines between them.
I was using `(?s).*?` but it just matches if you have one line or more.
Any idea?

Here is an example:

Output I was looking for in both input 1 and 2 is:
Input 1:

```
buy
buy
net premium
no. of units
425
426
```

Input 2:

```
buy
buy
net premium
no. of units
425
xxx
yyy
426
```

output expected:

```
buy
buy
425
426
```

I was thinking to use something like

```
(buy|sell)
(buy|sell)
(?s).*?
(\d*)
(\d*) | (?s).*?\n(\d*)
```

where  `(?s).*?\n(\d*)` is like either a number or a certain nb of line and a number. But it doesn't work

I need a regex to cover both cases.

Comment: Please include the language or framework you are working in. While many regex APIs have similarities, there is no one standard, and it's important to know which library you're using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I was trying to get it just under https://regex101.com/. Adding that detail in my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work in every language or library, but `[\s\S]` is a handy way of matching everything, including newlines, in cases where `.` won't match newlines (and certain other whitespace characters).

If you think of the newlines as just more characters to match, then you can use an expression like this to capture the desired text in groups:

```
(buy|sell)\n(buy|sell)[\s\S]*^(\d+)[\s\S]*^(\d+)
```

[regex permalink](https://regex101.com/r/Viefap/1)

Note that this example will not work in JavaScript, though it works fine in PHP, Golang and Python.